# Message was sending but not received

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using fcm gem.

This is my code:

```ruby
module NotificationHelper
  require 'fcm'

  def send_notification(location, message,user_id )
    firebase_key = Rails.application.secrets.firebase_key

    user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    fcm = FCM.new(firebase_key)
    registration_ids= [user.device_token] # an array of one or more client registration tokens
    options = {:data => {"message": message, "location": location}}
    response = fcm.send(registration_ids, options)
  end
end
```

This is my response:

> {"status_code": 200,
>           "response": "success",
>           "canonical_ids": [],
>           "not_registered_ids": []}

Comment: registration_ids= [user.device_token]  i can change this line for registration_ids=user.device_token 
"status_code": 400,  and i got following result.
        "response": "Only applies for JSON requests. Indicates that the request could not be parsed as JSON, or it contained invalid fields."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Your option for following:

```
options = {
        priority: 'high',
        data: {
            message: message,
            location: location
        },
        notification: {
            body: message,
            location: location,
            sound: 'default'
        }
    }
```

This is works for me.